# Reversing an XOR encryption/decryption function

Tags: encryption, symmetric, xor, decryption, encoding

I have a help recommended high-school project that I'm stuck with. To basically explain the problem: I have an encryption function that is used as the decryption function and I need to reverse it to make an encryption function.

I tried many things but I can't find the proper result. The best I came with was to encrypt 1 byte on 2 properly.

Here is the core of the function (the rest is variables initialization:

```
// Decrypt
for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    decrypted_msg[i] = (xor_key[i % 128] - i) ^ (encrypted_msg[i] - i / 16 - 12);
}
```

So can someone explain me (like I'm five) how to reverse this code to produce the encryption?

Thank you by advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

`decrypted_msg[i] = (xor_key[i % 128] - i) ^ (encrypted_msg[i] - i / 16 - 12);`

convert this into equations

\begin{align}
p[i] &= (\phantom{(}key[i \bmod 128]-i) \oplus (c[i] - i/16 -12)\\
c[i] - i/16 -12 &= (\phantom{(}key[i \bmod 128]-i) \oplus p[i]\\
c[i] - i/16 &= \left( (key[i \bmod 128]-i) \oplus p[i] \right) +12\\
c[i] &= \left( (key[i \bmod 128]-i) \oplus p[i] \right) +12 +i/16
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked flawlessly. And big thank for the equations!

Comment: You can edit my answer and take the $\LaTeX$ code, too. What kind of project is this on what kind of school?

Comment: I'm in normal highschool in France, it's a project about reversing communication protocol at my school's computer club.

Comment: I  hope getting help was not prohibited

Comment: No, don't worry. It's even recommended. :)